# Spanning sets in linear block codes

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Let $C$ be a binary linear code of length $n$ and rank $k$. Say that a codeword $c\in C$ *satisfies the $i$-property in $C$* if $c$ has a $1$ in the $i$-th position and $$w(c)=min\{w(c') : c'\in C\text{ and $c'$ has a $1$ in the $i$-th position}\}$$ where $w(c)$ denotes the weight of $c$. Suppose that $C$ contains a subset $X$ such that $|X|\ge k$, and, for each $i$, $1\le i\le n$, there exists $x\in X$ such that $x$ satisfies the $i$-property. I thought it might be interesting to think about the question: how small (in terms of dimension) can $Span_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}(X)$ be? For instance, if $k=n$, then $Span_{\mathbb{Z}_{2}}(X)$ must be the entire code. It seems intuitive that $X$ must generate a "large" space. Apologies in advance if my question is trivial, and for the terminology *$i$-property* - I've only just started to look at linear coding, so my knowledge is sparse to say the least! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific goal in mind, or is this just idle toying with an idea? The idea in my answer is to cover all the positions with a small number of minimally overlapping minimal weight words, and then go from there. There are some related reasonably seriously studied question such as: do the minimum weight words span the entire code? IIRC the answer is known to be affirmative for many well-studied families of codes. I think that there are reasonably interesting codes that don't have that property, but I can't produce one right now.

Comment: @Jyrki: Thank you for your counterexample. We can view $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{n}$  as a module for a subgroup $H$ of the symmetric group Sym(n), over the field of two elements, GF(2) (the H-action is given by permutation of coordinates). Suppose that $C$ is a $H$-submodule. The reason for thinking about the posted question was: how small can we make our generating set for $C$ as a $H$-module, provided that H is transitive? If $x$ was an element of $C$ satisfying the i-property, for some $i$, then the $H$-orbit of $x$ would be a subset $X$ as in the post (although we may not have $|X|\ge k$ here)..

Comment: .. and the span of $X$ can be generated, as a $H$-module, by $1$ element.

Comment: That is not very different from how I thought about it. Undoubtedly you noticed that in my example all of $S_n$ is a symmetry-group. The case $H=C_n$, i.e. the cyclic codes, is a widely studied case. For many a class of cyclic codes the symmetry group is a bit bigger, and can be used in studying/proving properties of the codes. A doubly transitive symmetry group is relatively common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not difficult to introduce a lot of linear dependencies to $X$. The first possibility that occurred to me involves the even weight $[n,n-1,2]$ code $C$.

For example, let $n=17$, and let $X$ consist of those ten ($10={5\choose 2}$) words of weight two that have their two non-zero bits within the first five positions, together with the six words 
$00000\, 110000\, 000000$, $00000\, 001100\, 000000$, $00000\, 000011\, 000000$, $00000\, 000000\, 110000$, $00000\, 000000\, 001100$, $00000\, 000000\, 000011$. 
So $X$ consists of 16 weight two words such that their ones occur at all positions. Thus $X$ has the $i$-property for all $i$. Yet the set $X$ only spans a 10-dimensional subspace inside the 16-dimensional code $C$. The first ten vectors all belong to a 4-dimensional subspace, and the last six listed codes all add a dimension to the span of $X$.

It seems easy to increase the gap between the dimension of the entire code, and the span of $X$ by picking a larger $n$. I also think it's likely that something similar happens with e.g. most large Reed-Muller codes.

Note BTW: In the example above all the words in $X$ have the $i$-property for some $i$. If we allow "ballast inside $X$", we can widen the gap in the above example further by covering all the bit position with nine linearly independent weight two words, and then use their higher weight linear combinations to increase the size of $X$ as large as you required it to be.